# Can I cause an exception on purpose in python?

Tags: python, exception, testing

So this is a little bit of a strange question, but it could be fun!

I need  to somehow reliably cause an exception in python. I would prefer it to be human triggered, but I am also willing to embed something in my code that will always cause an exception. (I have set up some exception handling and would like to test it)

I've been looking around and some ideas appear to be division by zero or something along those lines will always cause an exception--Is there a better way? The most ideal would be to simulate a loss of internet connection while the program is running....any ideas would be great!

Have fun!

Comment: You can just put in your code: ``raise ...``, e.g. ``raise TypeError`` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is:  You can explicitly raise your own exceptions.

```
raise Exception("A custom message as to why you raised this.")
```

You would want to raise an appropriate exception/error for loss of network connectivity.

Answer (score 4):

You can define your own Exceptions in Python, so you can create custom errors to suit your needs. You can test that certain conditions exist, and use the truthiness of that test to decide whether or not to raise your shiny, custom Exception:

```
class MyFancyException(Exception): pass

def do_something():
    if sometestFunction() is True:
        raise MyFancyException
    carry_on_theres_nothing_to_see()    

try:
    do_something()
except MyFancyException:
    # This is entirely up to you! 
    # What needs to happen if the exception is caught?
```

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.2/tutorial/errors.html#tut-userexceptions) has some useful examples.

Comment: This is really good too! I'll be creating my own sometime when I get an extra minute. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you can just plop

```
  1 / 0
```

anywhere in your code for a run time error to occur, specifically in this case a `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero`.

This is the simplest way to get an exception by embedding something in your code (as you mentioned in your post). You can of course raise your own Exceptions too .. depends on your specific needs.

Comment: ...what good would that do?  It doesn't do a sufficient job of representing whatever error that's wanted to be simulated; it's just a `ZeroDivisionError` instead.

Comment: @Makoto To quote OP: " I am also willing to embed something in my code that will always cause an exception" .. you best direct your comment at OP.